# Conda env not loading correct version of numpy

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, conda, miniconda

I'm running [**miniconda2**](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) (python2.7 install). Rather than try to use **miniconda3** side by side, I tried just creating a python3.5 environment. However, when I try to import numpy I get an error because python tries to load numpy for python2.7. I'm assuming this is because of the environment variables set in my `.bashrc` which point to the **miniconda2** installation.

What is the best way to fix this? Is there a way I can use conda python2 and python3 side by side?

My `.bashrc` has:

```
export PYTHONLIB="/home/exacloud/lustre1/CompBio/miniconda2/lib"
export PYTHONPATH="/home/exacloud/lustre1/CompBio/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
export PYTHONUSERBASE="/home/exacloud/lustre1/CompBio/miniconda2"
export CONDA_BIN="/home/exacloud/lustre1/CompBio/miniconda2/bin"
```

Session:

```
balter@s-3-5:~$ conda create -n p3 python=3 pandas numpy
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /<path>/miniconda2/envs/p3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:            1.1-openblas                  conda-forge
    ca-certificates: 2016.8.31-0                   conda-forge
    certifi:         2016.8.31-py35_0              conda-forge
    libgfortran:     3.0.0-1
    ncurses:         5.9-9                         conda-forge
    numpy:           1.11.2-py35_blas_openblas_200 conda-forge [blas_openblas]
    openblas:        0.2.18-5                      conda-forge
    openssl:         1.0.2h-2                      conda-forge
    pandas:          0.19.0-np111py35_0            conda-forge
    pip:             8.1.2-py35_0                  conda-forge
    python:          3.5.2-2                       conda-forge
    python-dateutil: 2.5.3-py35_0                  conda-forge
    pytz:            2016.7-py35_0                 conda-forge
    readline:        6.2-0                         conda-forge
    setuptools:      26.1.1-py35_0                 conda-forge
    six:             1.10.0-py35_1                 conda-forge
    sqlite:          3.13.0-1                      conda-forge
    tk:              8.5.19-0                      conda-forge
    wheel:           0.29.0-py35_0                 conda-forge
    xz:              5.2.2-0                       conda-forge
    zlib:            1.2.8-3                       conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Linking packages ...
[                    ]|                                                                            [ca-certificates     ]|                                                                            [libgfortran         ]|####                                                                        [ncurses             ]|########                                                                    [sqlite              ]|#############                                                               [tk                  ]|#################                                                           [openblas            ]|#######################                                              |  33%
Screen session on s (system load: 1.12 1.05 0.91)               Thu 27.10.2016 14:43
    wheel:           0.29.0-py35_0                 conda-forge
    xz:              5.2.2-0                       conda-forge
    zlib:            1.2.8-3                       conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Linking packages ...
[                    ]|                                                                           [ca-certificates     ]|                                                                           [libgfortran         ]|####                                                                       [ncurses             ]|########                                                                   [sqlite              ]|#############                                                              [tk                  ]|#################                                                          [openb[      COMPLETE      ]|######################################################################| 100%
No psutil available.
To proceed, please conda install psutil#
# To activate this environment, use:
# $ source activate p3
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# $ source deactivate
#
balter@s-3-5:~$
balter@s-3-5:~$ source activate p3
(p3) balter@s-3-5:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 26 2016, 01:32:08)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<path>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/<path>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/<path>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/<path>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/<path>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)
>>>
```

Comment: Have you installed psutils in your virtualenv as stated by conda?

Comment: @P.Camilleri can you please point me to that? I don't see anything about psutils in the [docs I've been following](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html). However, perhaps I should try `conda create -n p3 python=3 anaconda`. Would that insure that the right version of numpy is linked?

Comment: Weel there was a line in the code you included which said No psutil available. To proceed, please conda install psutil. But it looks like you fixed your issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in your `.bashrc`:

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#resolution-for-python-packages-make-sure-you-have-not-set-the-pythonpath-or-pythonhome-variable

Activating the conda environment should take care of ensuring that all of your paths work with the packages in the environment.

Comment: Thanks! I did `unset PYTHONPATH` and numpy imported properly inside the env. Question: if I remove that environment variable from my `.bashrc` altogether, what will happen if I run python outside of a specified environment. For instance, just log in and type `python`?

Comment: You will get whichever python comes first on your `$PATH`. If you let miniconda modify your path, then it will be the "root" environment from miniconda. To check, see what you get if you run `which python`.

Comment: Got it. I put the `CONDA_BIN` miniconda created before my path, and started my path with `export PATH="$CONDA_BIN:/usr/bin...."`. Works as hoped for.